# while running terraform script to launch aws instance getting this error

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

while running terraform script to launch aws instance getting this error

```
Error: Invalid AWS Region: us-west-2a

  on provider.tf line 1, in provider "aws":
   1: provider "aws" {
```

This is my provider.tf

```
provider "aws" {
  region  = "${var.region}"
  version = "~> 2.0"
}
```

can anybody help out?

Answer (score 1):

`us-west-2a` is an availability zone inside the `us-west-2` region. You need to fix your `var.region` value.